# Узнать список страниц

Tags: html, java

Добрый день,

Можно ли вытащить список страниц сайта, например 
http://www.klassika.ru/stihi/lermontov/  ?

К примеру я могу пройти по ссылке http://www.klassika.ru/stihi/lermontov/lyublyu-tebya-bulatnyj.html

А как можно узнать сколько страниц находится ниже уровня http://www.klassika.ru/stihi/lermontov/ и вырвать список названий страниц?

Можно ли это сделать с помощью Java?

Answer (score 4):

С помощью Джавы Вы даже и не подозреваете чего наделать можете. А относительно Вашего вопроса все очень просто делается с библиотекой [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/), можете загрузить страницу так:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
...
String url = "http://www.klassika.ru/stihi/lermontov/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Затем выделить все ссылки:

**Вариант 1**

```
 Elements frame = doc.select("a");
 for(int i=0; i<frame.size(); i++){
    String attrHref = frame.get(i).attr("href");
    if(attrHref.countains(url)&&attrHref.length>url.length){
     //Нашли ссылку ниже уровнем и делайте с ними, что хотите теперь.
     //Можно выделить ссылки определенного класса или с определенным атрибутом.
    }
 }
```

**Вариант 2**

```
Elements frames = doc.body().getElementsByTagName("a");
for (Element frame : frames)
{
    String text = frame.attr("href");
    if (text.contains(url) & text.length() > url.length())
    {
        //Код
    }
}
```